# datatable doesn't show row selection

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to move from RichFaces to Primefaces (fresh download 7.0 ver.) and specifically trying to use datatable.
I get a weird behavior because some properties of the datatable seem not to work, like resizableColumns or draggableColumns and particularly I cannot see the rows change color when the cursor moves on it. In this way, I'm not able to select and process any row.

I tried to change the theme but nothing changes.
I tried to change selection mode to one command button per row and in this way, it seems to work (I can see the row key selected in debugging).

I'm working with netbeans 8.2, java 1.8 and tomcat 8.0.27  on win10

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:es="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/esutils">

    <h:form id="ESSocform">
        <p:panel header="#{mess.titleListSoc}" styleClass="ES_contentGlo">
            <div id="ESSocContentMain" >
                <p:dataTable id="ESSocTable"
                             var="item" 
                             value="#{eSSoc.dataModel}" 
                             frozenColumns="2"
                             selectionMode="single" 
                             selection="#{eSSoc.selection}" 
                             rowKey="#{item.a2id}"  
                             resizableColumns="true" 
                             draggableColumns="true" 
                             disabledSelection="false"
                             >
```

What I'd like to do is like the example shown in PF showcase for the datatable's "select event" example.

Comment: Please try to do as in the example then (but make sure you follow all basic jsf 'rules' that are not explicitly mentioned in the examples but assume to be existing knowledge)

Comment: Hi, there is some big mistake you've already seen in my code ?

Comment: Yes, that it is not a [mcve]... See also https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: This is all mentioned in [tour] and [ask] btw, maybe also read them again...

Comment: Hi, does the `eSSoc.getDataModel()` method return a `Collection` of entities? If so, does your entity implements the `equals` and `hash` methods?

Comment: @OscarPérez: Good questions, but there are many more... which should all be automagically answered in a  real [mcve]... ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje: I totally agree, just pointed some obvious and tipical error points

Comment: thanks to all for the suggestions. at last i found. i took from the showcase the code of the datatable "select events" and "as is" the table works correctly, but just as i add the "frozenColumns" attribute it became working as mine datatable, no selection enabled, no resize or moveable columns. i don't know if this is a knonwn bug but for me it works as described.